How to use axios-cookiejar-support with proxy?
I need to use proxy e.g. SocksProxyAgent in axios, and at the same time cookiejar:
import { Cookie, CookieJar } from "tough-cookie";
import { wrapper } from "axios-cookiejar-support";

const axiosConfig: AxiosRequestConfig<any> = {
    headers: {},
    maxRedirects: 0,
    jar: this.cookieJar, // Use tough-cookie jar
    withCredentials: true, // Required for axios to use the cookie jar
};

this.request = wrapper(axios.create(axiosConfig));
    
const proxyAgent = new SocksProxyAgent(proxy);
this.request.defaults.httpAgent = proxyAgent;//error here
this.request.defaults.httpsAgent = proxyAgent;

But I get this error:
axios-cookiejar-support does not support for use with other http(s).Agent.

